# bin/bash echo > if keyword is not writing into file

Tags: bash

I've a script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "<?php
  if (!defined('MACHINE_ID')) {
      define('MACHINE_ID','SERVER_ID');
  }
" > /var/www/html/NODE20_CONFIG.php
```

but after running it , the output file

```
cat NODE20_CONFIG.php 

<?php

      define('MACHINE_ID','SERVER_ID');
  }
```

why line with
if(!defined('MACHINE_ID')) {
is missing from the output file ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce it in an interactive shell. Error message: `-bash: !defined: event not found`

Comment: Check for Carriage Return characters in the script. Fix it with `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem in an interactive session using bash 4.4.20. There, bash interprets `!` as *history substituion*. When you write `!abc` bash replaces that string by the last command starting with `abc`, even when inside double quotes `"..."`.

You can easily disable expansion of `!` using single quotes `'...'` (not an option here, since your string already contains single quotes) or a quoted here-document:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<'EOF' > /var/www/html/NODE20_CONFIG.php
<?php
  if (!defined('MACHINE_ID')) {
      define('MACHINE_ID','SERVER_ID');
  }
EOF
```

However, I really wonder why you got this problem. By default, history substition is disabled in scripts. You can manually enable it using `set -H -o history`, but I don't see such a thing in your script. Did you really run the script file, or did you just copy-paste it into your terminal?

Comment: indeed, did not know about history substitution. Works like a charm. Thanks!